# Setup and create project in Eclipse

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I am trying to setup Eclipse and Force.com for doing SF development.  I have done a lot of apex, VF, PB/Flow, and other development in SF but all through the main interface.  The standard apex editor is horrible and I wanted to experiment with Eclipse.  I installed it and the Force.com addin successfully.  I tried to create a new test project on my Test sandbox.  I successfully connected, but it hung while choosing initial project contents.  The choice window displayed a blank grey screen, so I clicked finish.  The progress window displayed, but it seems to be hung for the last hour.  What am I missing?[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78664/discussion-on-question-by-jerry-welliver-setup-and-create-project-in-eclipse).

Comment: IntelliJ + illuminatedCloud is a nicer alternative (as are other IDEs) as Force.com Eclipse IDE hasn't been updated